# How to project more than the first sub-document when using $elemMatch

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate, projection, mongodb-java

I have a collection with documents of the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "67bg............"},
    "ID"  : "xxxxxxxx",
    "senses" : [
        {
            "word"   : "hello",
            "lang"   : "EN",
            "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY"
        },
        {
            "word"   : "coche",
            "lang"   : "ES",
            "source" : "ES_DICTIONARY"
        },
        {
            "word"   : "bye",
            "lang"   : "EN",
            "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all documents that match at least one sense with `lang=X` and `source=Y` and return the matched Documents with only those `senses` which match `lang=X` and `source=Y`.

I tried this:

```
DBObject sensesQuery = new BasicDBObject();
sensesQuery.put("lang", "EN");
sensesQuery.put("source", "EN_DICTIONARY");
DBObject matchQuery = new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",sensesQuery);

DBObject fields = new BasicDBOject();
fields.put("senses",matchQuery);

DBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
projection.put("ID",1)
projection.put("senses",matchQuery);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(fields,projection)

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

My query works for matching documents, but not for the projection. Taking the above document as an example, if I run my query I get this result:

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "67bg............"},
    "ID"  : "xxxxxxxx",
    "senses" : [
        {
            "word"   : "hello",
            "lang"   : "EN",
            "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want this :

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "67bg............"},
    "ID"  : "xxxxxxxx",
    "senses" : [
        {
            "word"   : "hello",
            "lang"   : "EN",
            "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY"
        },
        {
            "word"   : "bye",
            "lang"   : "EN",
            "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY"
        }
    ]
}
```

I read about aggregation but I did not understand how to use it in the MongoDB Java driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `$elemMatch` operator on the projection aswell as on the filter.

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

> The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition.

So, the behaviour you are seeing **is** the expected behaviour for elemMatch-in-a-projection.

If you want to project all sub documents in the `senses` array within documents which match the filter condition then you could use this:

```
projection.put("senses", 1);
```

But, if you want to project only those sub documents which match your filter condition then `$elemMatch` will not work for you since it only ever returns the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition. Your alternative is to use the aggregation framework, for example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // matches documents with a senses sub document having the given lang and source values
  {$match: {'senses.lang': 'EN', 'senses.source': 'EN_DICTIONARY'}},

  // projects on the senses sub document and filters the output to only return sub 
  // documents having the given lang and source values
  {$project: {
      senses: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$senses",
            as: "sense",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$sense.lang", 'EN' ], $eq: [ "$$sense.source", 'EN_DICTIONARY' ] }
          }
        }
      }
  }
])
```

Here's that aggregation call using the MongoDB Java driver:

```
Document filter = new Document("senses.lang", "EN").append("senses.source", "EN_DICTIONARY");

DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
filterExpression.put("input", "$senses");
filterExpression.put("as", "sense");
filterExpression.put("cond", new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.<Object>asList(
        new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$sense.lang", "EN")),
        new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$sense.source", "EN_DICTIONARY")))
));

BasicDBObject projectionFilter = new BasicDBObject("$filter", filterExpression);

AggregateIterable<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$match", filter),
        new Document("$project", new Document("senses", projectionFilter))));

for (Document document : documents) {
    logger.info("{}", document.toJson());
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
2017-10-01 17:15:39 [main] INFO  c.s.mongo.MongoClientTest - { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59d10cdfc26584cd8b7a0d3b" }, "senses" : [{ "word" : "hello", "lang" : "EN", "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY" }, { "word" : "bye", "lang" : "EN", "source" : "EN_DICTIONARY" }] }
```

**Update 1**: following this comment:

> After a long period of testing, trying to understand why the query was slow, I noticed that the "$match" parameter does not work, the query should select only records that have at least one sense with source = Y AND lang = X and project them , but the query also returns me documents with senses = []

This filter: `new Document("senses.lang", "EN").append("senses.source", "EN_DICTIONARY")` will not match documents which have no `senses` attribute nor will it match documents which have an empty `senses` attribute. To verify this I added the following documents to my own collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d72a24c26584cd8b7b70a5"),
    "ID" : "yyyyyyyy"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d72a3ac26584cd8b7b70ae"),
    "ID" : "zzzzzzzzz",
    "senses" : []
}
```

And re ran the above code and I still get the desired result.

I suspect your statment that the above code does not work is either a false negative or the documents you are querying are different to the sample I have been working with.

To help you diagnose this issue for yourself you could ...

- Play around with other operators e.g. the `$match` stage behaves the same with and without an `$exists` operator:

  ```
  new Document("senses", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true))
          .append("senses.lang", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "EN"))
          .append("senses.source", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "EN_DICTIONARY"))
  ```
- Remove the `$project` stage to see exactly what the `$match` stage produces.

Comment: AggregationOutput hasn't method .into();

Comment: It does in v3.5 :) but that's a secondary matter since that's just syntactic sugar for outputing to a list. I have updated the answer to return an `AggregateIterable`. The key points in that answer, though, are (1) why elemMatch on a projection is only returning you the first entry and (2) how to perform the same filter via the aggregation framework and (3) how to express such an aggregation via the MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: Ok,it works, now, how to add (from your answer) "$eq: [ "$$sense.source", 'EN_DICTIONARY' ]" into the filterExpression, in and with first condition( "$$sense.lang" , "EN")?

Comment: @ChristianSordi I have updated the answer, you'll notice that the `"cond"` attribute of the `filterExpression` now wraps two `$eq` in an `$and`.

Comment: After a long period of testing, trying to understand why the query was slow, I noticed that the "$match" parameter does not work, the query should select only records that have at least one sense with source = Y AND lang = X and project them , but the query also returns me documents with senses = [] and this is not possible because if the document respects the filter conditions it should have projected at least one sense.